# Progress bars in for loops

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a couple of questions about progress bars and for loops.
I admit I am quite new to all this so I hope my question makes sense.

I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express WMA.

I am using the following code to fill my progress bars.

```
new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(0);

    vProgressBar0.BeginInvoke(
        new Action(() =>
            {
                vProgressBar0.Value = ((vTotal* 100) / vGames);
            }));

}));
backgroundThread0.Start();
```

I have a number of progress bars that I need to fill. They are labeled vProgressBar0, vProgressBar1,vProgressBar2, etc. This code does what I need but it is quite repetitive
to fill all the progress bars.

I would like to use a "For" loop with the value "i" as my counter to fill the progress bars.

I am able to replace the " vProgressBar0.BeginInvoke" statement with `this.Controls[vProgressBar + i].BeginInvoke()` and it works fine.

My question is: I cannot find a way to replace the `vProgressBar0.Value = ((vTotal* 100) / vGames)` statement with anything that will use the "i" value in my for loop. Any thoughts?

Will I be able to use the backgroundThread0 for all the progress bars in the for loop or will I need to increment that value also? ( e.g. backgroundThread0, backgroundThread1, etc.) As I am also having trouble getting that value to increment.

Comment: OMG, this is TERRIFYING code... There are so many things wrong with this. You're newing up a `Thread`, really?  If you want to iterate the know progress bar controls, put them in an array.

Comment: I guess you could make some kind of an array or list of all the objects and then loop through that list.

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic, simply put the `ProgressBar` instances in an array and iterate over them. Since this is so straightforward, I would advise against using `new ThreadStart` as you need to have a better understanding of general programming practices.

```
private readonly ProgressBar[] _bars = 
    new[]
    {
        vProgressBar0, vProgressBar1, vProgressBar2, vProgressBar3
    };

public void StartProgress()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _bars.Length; ++ i)
    {
        var progressBar = _bars[i]; // If "i == 0" this is the "vProgressBar0" instance.
        // Use it here...
    }
}
```